# random world generation issues

Tags: javascript, procedural-generation

I am writing a pathfinding function to create rivers for my random world generator that takes a random spot on the map with high moisture and elevation and proceeds to choose the adjacent pixels, finds the one with the lowest elevation and continues that in a loop until it either reaches the edge of the map or hits water.
 The world generator as a whole creates an elevation and moisture map using midpoint displacement and then compares both maps to evaluate biomes and water. This part works fine, its just when I implement my river creation function, the page doesn't load up and i cant check my river array in the console when debugging. 
  Pretty much the only issue Im having is with the setRivers function. I dont know if I tossed in an infinite loop on accident, if theres a bug, or if the river mechanic is just crap.

Heres my code:

```js
    function createMap(size) {
      var map = [];
      for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        map[x] = [];
        for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
          map[x][y] = 0;
        }
      }
      map[0][0] = 128;
      map[size - 1][0] = 128;
      map[size - 1][size - 1] = 128;
      map[0][size - 1] = 128;
      midpoint(0, 0, size - 1, size - 1);
      return map;

      function midpoint(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        if (x2 - x1 < 2 && y2 - y1 < 2) {
          return;
        }
        var dist = (x2 - x1 + y2 - y1);
        var hdist = Math.floor(dist / 2);
        var rx = function(n, d) {
          return Math.floor(((n + Math.floor(Math.random() * dist) - hdist) / d));
        };
        // var r2 = function(n) { return Math.floor(((n + Math.floor(Math.random() * dist) - hdist) / 2)); };
        var set = function(x, y, n) {
          if (map[x][y] == 0) {
            map[x][y] = rx(n, 2);
          }
        };

        var midx = Math.floor((x1 + x2) / 2);
        var midy = Math.floor((y1 + y2) / 2);
        var c1 = map[x1][y1];
        var c2 = map[x2][y1];
        var c3 = map[x2][y2];
        var c4 = map[x1][y2];
        set(midx, y1, c1 + c2);
        set(midx, y2, c4 + c3);
        set(x1, midy, c1 + c4);
        set(x2, midy, c2 + c3);
        map[midx][midy] = rx(c1 + c2 + c3 + c4, 4);
        midpoint(x1, y1, midx, midy);
        midpoint(midx, y1, x2, midy);
        midpoint(x1, midy, midx, y2);
        midpoint(midx, midy, x2, y2);
      }
    }

    function getColor(elevation, moisture, river) {
      var cb = function(e, m) {
        return (elevation >= e && moisture >= m);
      };
      var ce = function(e) {
        return elevation >= e;
      };
      var cm = function(m) {
        return moisture >= m;
      };
      if (cb(250, 178)) {
        return "#FFFFFF";
      } //snow
      if (cb(250, 142)) {
        return "#CCFFFF";
      } //tundra
      if (cb(250, 100)) {
        return "#808080";
      } //bare
      if (ce(250)) {
        return "black";
      } //scorched
      if (cb(175, 214)) {
        return "#006600";
      } //taiga
      if (cb(175, 142)) {
        return "#009933";
      } //shrubland
      if (ce(175)) {
        return "#FFCC66";
      } //temperate desert
      if (cb(100, 250)) {
        return "#00FF99";
      } //temperate rainforest
      if (cb(100, 178)) {
        return "#00CC00";
      } //temperate deciduous forest
      if (cb(100, 100)) {
        return "#CCFF33";
      } //grassland
      if (ce(100)) {
        return "#FFCC66";
      } //temperate desert
      if (cm(214)) {
        return "#336600";
      } //tropical rainforeest
      if (cm(142)) {
        return "#339966";
      } //tropical seasonal forest
      if (cm(100)) {
        return "#CCFF33";
      } //grassland
      if (cm(70)) {
        return "orange";
      } //subtropical desert
      return "blue"; //water

    }

    function setRivers(es, ms, size) {
      var riverMap = [];
      for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        riverMap[x] = [];
        for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
          riverMap[x][y] = 0;
        }
      }
      var riverChance = 30;
      for (var x = 1; x < size; x++) {
        for (var y = 1; y < size; y++) {
          if (es[x][y] > 175 && ms[x][y] > 142) {
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
            var hitWater = false;
            var hitEdge = false;
            var ex = x;
            var ey = y;
            if (r >= riverChance) {
              riverMap[ex][ey] = 1;
              while (hitWater == false && hitEdge == false) {
                var neighbors = [es[ex - 1][ey], es[ex + 1][ey], es[ex][ey + 1], es[ex][ey - 1], es[ex][ey]];
                //                 north     ,       south,     east,     west,      current position
                var lowestElevation = 0;
                for (var i = 1; i < neighbors.length; i++) {
                  if (neighbors[i] < neighbors[lowestElevation]) lowestElevation = i;
                }
                switch (lowestElevation) {
                  case 0:
                    riverMap[ex - 1][ey] = 'r';
                    ex -= 1;
                    break;
                  case 1:
                    riverMap[ex + 1][ey] = 'r';
                    ex += 1;
                    break;
                  case 2:
                    riverMap[ex][ey + 1] = 'r';
                    ey += 1;
                    break;
                  case 3:
                    riverMap[ex][ey - 1] = 'r';
                    ey -= 1;
                    break;
                  case 4:
                    hitWater = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (ex == 1 || ey == 1 || ex == (size - 1) || ey == (size - 1)) {
                  hitEdge = true;
                }
                if (es[ex][ey] < 100 && ms[ex][ey] < 70) {
                  hitWater = true;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return river;
    }

    function createWorld(worldSize) {
      var size = worldSize;
      var es = createMap(size);
      var ms = createMap(size);
      var rs = setRivers(es, ms, size);
      console.log(river);
      var draw = function(ctx) {
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            ctx.fillStyle = getColor(es[i][j], ms[i][j]);
            ctx.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
            if (river[i][j] == 1) {
              ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
              ctx.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
            }
          }
        }
      };
      return {
        size: size,
        elevation: es,
        moisture: ms,
        river: rs,
        draw: draw
      };
    }

    var world = createWorld(513);
    var c = document.getElementById("main");
    world.draw(c.getContext("2d"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <canvas id='main' height='768' width='1024'></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm looking through it, right now; so far, you've got some reference errors at the botttom (`river is not defined`), in your `createWorld`. Of course, you never hit that part, because you're locking the thread, hard.

I think part of the problem might be that you're going from a 30% chance of a river to a 70% chance. `if (random > riverChance)` where `random` is `1 - 100`. At 70% chance, I believe you may be exploding your generator, on a 513^2 map, on a per-pixel basis. Still hunting.

Comment: Using a simplified codebase for just determining where the springs are, which feed the rivers, on a 150^2 map, I'm getting somewhere between 0 - 100 springs, per page refresh. That's using the 30% chance, not the 70%, and it's a fraction of the scale of the original map.  Your culprit is that the browser is very single-threaded, and you're hogging it with this algorithm. In order to make this work, you really need to separate the construction of these, into multiple timeouts.

Comment: The one other suggestion I'd have, looking at this immediately, is to build your array of world tiles once, and for each tile (/pixel, though it'd be good to abstract the two from one another), make one node, where you assign an elevation and a moisture level, determine if it's a spring, give it known coordinates, so that it doesn't have to live within the confines of a double-loop, for everything you want to do with it...

Comment: Ah yes I forgot that i changed the river variable to riverMap during late development that's a face palm and another face palm for the random chance deal. Thanks for the multi threading suggestion too, I should definitely implement that. I havent really worked with multi threading in javascript before but there's a first time for everything right? Thats an awesome idea about the nodes, Ill definitely implement that

Comment: It's not even multithreading, so much as it's deferring remaining processing until later, so that the host can do something again. With this algorithm, you're doing millions of iterations, before the browser is allowed to redraw, or listen for clicks or keypresses, et cetera. So sharding it, and batching those processes, with little breathers in between will take longer, but at least will be responsive. It is also possible to use WebWorkers for exactly this type of calculation, in a separate process, and post back to the main thread with the bulk result.

Comment: I see, and I was just looking at webworkers!

Comment: Fixed my code, I split the river generation into steps like you said, cleaned it up and got the rivers to start working! That was awhile ago though, and now I've run into a pretty serious bug and I can't figure out how to fix it. I could post my new code in another question but I feel like asking for free debugging on Stack is pretty frowned upon...